# Saving A Variable with SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure where I delete files from my database.

But I'm getting an error when I execute my query that I have more then one value which is correct.

But I want to delete all the values in my table. Without getting the error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteArticle]
@Article_ID int
AS

DECLARE @IDS int
SET @IDS = (SELECT [File_ID] FROM Article_Files WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID);

DELETE FROM Article_Files WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID;
DELETE FROM Files WHERE [FILE_ID] IN (@IDS);
DELETE FROM Article WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID;
RETURN 0
```

The error is in de 5-6 six line of code where I SET the @IDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store result of `SELECT` that returns many items into `INT` variable

```
DECLARE @IDS int
SET @IDS = (SELECT [File_ID] FROM Article_Files WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID);
```

In this case, the `@IDS` value will be the last `File_ID` of `SELECT`

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (Id INT)
INSERT INTO @Ids
SELECT [File_ID] FROM Article_Files WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID

DELETE FROM Article_Files WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID;
DELETE FROM Files WHERE [FILE_ID] IN (SELECT Id FROM @Ids);
DELETE FROM Article WHERE Article_ID = @Article_ID;
RETURN 0
```

Comment: I cannot do that because im deleting the Article_Files first. because of FK conditions.

Comment: Thankyou that was the solution! :)